React complains about react-icons HiSparkle's 'dataSlot' property
I add <HiSparkles/> to my react app, and I keep getting:
Warning: React does not recognize the dataSlotprop on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute, spell it as lowercasedataslot instead. If you accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM element. .
I tried to wrap the element in various ways, such as inside a React fragment or some kind of nested component, but keep getting this. I changed now the element to <IoSparklesSharp /> and it works flawlessly.
Is there something special about <HiSparkles /> ?

How are you importing it?

import { HiSparkles } from "react-icons/hi"
